# Paso de valores de Atributos entre objetos de una clases en Python

Tags: python-3.x, diseño-de-clases

Buenas noches a todos.

Tengo una consulta de fundamento en tipo de datos en Python. En pyhton, todas las variables son referencias (direccion) a un objeto, por tanto cuando se utiliza el operador de asignacion se crea el objeto(si no existe) y se pasa la direccion a la variable.
Mi problema esta en que deseo pasar los valores de atributos de un objeto de una clase a otro objeto, pero que ninguno de los dos cambie su direccion de memoria.
En el siguiente codigo **materiales** es un fichero y **Objeto** es una clase con muchos (bastantes) atributos.

**Fichero materiales.py**

```
class Objeto:
    def __init__(self, nombre: str = "Objeto1", color: str = "gris", peso: float = 20, acabado: str = "liso",
                 costo: float = 200000, unidad: str = "m"):
        self.__mombre = nombre
        self.__color = color
        self.__peso = peso
        self.__acabado = acabado
        self.__costounitario = costo
        self.__unidad = unidad
```

**Fichero principal**

```
L = [materiales.Objeto("1"), materiales.Objeto("2"), materiales.Objeto("3")]
a = L[0]
print(id(a))
print(id(L[0]))
L[0] = materiales.Objeto("4")  # Aqui es donde quiero que haya asignaciones entre cada atributo de ambos objetos
print(id(a))
print(id(L[0]))
```

Lo interior imprime que L[0] apunta hacia otro objeto (obviamente). Se crea el nuevo objeto **materiales.Objeto("4")** y su direccion de memoria se guarda en la primera posicion de la lista L[0]. Ahora, **materiales.Objeto("1")** sigue existiendo mediante referencia en **a**,

```
2212427398224
2212427398224
2212427398224
2214013122960
```

¿ La solucion estaria unicamente en crear metodos de clases donde yo haga el trabajo de asignar uno a uno los atributos de un objeto en otro ?. Son muchos atributos y me tocaria hacer esto para todas las clases, ¿ No existe algo que haga esto por defecto ?.
Por ejemplo en C++ el compilador construye por defecto la sobrecarga del operador de Asignacion permitiendo igualar los atributos mediante asignaciones entre objetos.

Este proceso es muy importante porque tengo otras clases que crean objetos, por ejemplo, elementos de un edificio (columnas, puertas, vigas, paneles, etc) en el cual un atributos es un material (referencia a una posicion de la lista de materiales) que exista en la lista **L** de materiales creados por el usuario. Si al intentar modificar algo de un material desde la lista(que funciona como un administrador) se cambia su direccion, todos los elementos que su material apuntaba no tendran acceso a ese cambio porque seguiran con la direccion al primer objeto.

Espero haber explicado de la mejor forma.

Gracias

Comment: Hola. No lo considere relevante porque la pregunta es independiente de correr el codigo. No es un problema de sintanxis del codigo sino de alcance del lenguaje de programacion. Igualmente acabo de completar toda la informacion. Cualquier ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: O sea, quieres tener dos objetos con distinta id() cuyos campos estén sincronizados, de modo que al cambiar el campo X uno, en el otro objeto también cambie el mismo campo X. ¿Correcto?

Comment: Nunca es bueno cambiar objetos. La _"mutabilidad"_ facilita algunas cosas, pero son muchos más los problemas que origina. No referencies objetos como elementos de una lista; mejor usa un diccionario inmutable (`MappingView`) y accede mediante una clave que no cambie. Por otro lado, los _Objetos_ créalos con _"dataclasses"_ y te será más fácil la reutilización de atributos (método `dataclass.replace()`). _((No tengo tiempo ahora para darte una respuesta completa))_

Comment: Hola ChemaCortes, Gracias por tu respuesta. El punto en tu respuesta es que la lista que contiene los "Materiales disponibles" puede cambiar y seguramente el usuario lo hará. Pero no puedo cambiar un objeto de la lista usando el operador de asignacion pq no se modifica sino que se crea uno nuevo objeto y pierdo la direccion de memoria que estaba en dicha posicion de la lista. Ahora, en mi ejemplo coloque solo datos para no desviar el enfoque de la pregunta pero las clases tienen muchos metodos y un diccionario no me ofrece esas virtudes. Voy a revisar los dataclass que me sugieres. Gracias !

Answer (score 0):

La solución más simple es definir un método para la clase que copie los atributos.

En este ejemplo tenemos un sólo atributo en la clase, pero pueden ser múltiples y de diversos tipos; la operación es la misma:

```
class Objeto:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor

    def copy(self, other):
        self.valor = other.valor

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.valor)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Entonces, en lugar de *reemplazar* un objeto de la lista, simplemente copiamos el contenido sobre el objeto ya existente:

```
lista = [Objeto(1)]
obj2 = lista[0]

obj3 = Objeto(3)
lista[0].copy(obj3)

print(lista)
print(obj2)
print(obj3)
```

produce:

```
[3]
3
3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hola Candid Moe, muchas Gracias. Como mencione en mi pregunta es eso lo que exactamente quiero evitar jeje... elaborar un metodo de copia para todas las clase de un proyecto es una gestion larga..., ahora pensando en esto, ¿ No se podria volver a llamar al constructor ___init__() y solo pasar los nuevos valores que quiero que se reemplacen ?.

Comment: El `__init__()` creara un nuevo objeto.